# How to get entities excluding navigation properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6 for one of my project. It has two entities Employee and EmployeeContacts. One employee can have many contacts and I have mapped these relationship in the database. When I return an Employee object it also returns EmployeeContacts that is related to the Employee. I want get only the Employee object excluding contact details

Answer (score 1):

You can use find: `var myEmployee = context.Employee.Find(id);`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx